# 3 column excel find value cell b2 in column a replace with cell c2

Tags: replace, excel-formula, find

using 3 columns 100k down column "a:a"= part desc with part number y400cc(webpage title) cell "b1"=old part number y400cc "c1"=new part number wpy400cc. 
*****Find cell b2 in column a and replace with cell c2  ?***

Comment: Home work question ? Pure code requests off topic here. Share what you have tried & where you are stuck.

Comment: take a look at the VLOOKUP function and the INDEX and MATCH FUNCTION

Comment: Whirlpool 6800 Microwave Filter 10097202 WP10097202             My mistake I need to look in column A  for b2 and if found replace with c2 .like the cells above 10097201 may be in a15000 when found I need to replace with WP10097202

Answer (score 0):

I am not Sure I understood your question fully. But here is my proposal:

1. Column A contains some text (Example: CELL A2 = "xx456yy")
2. Column B contains a part number which may or may not be found in A (Example CELL B2 = "456")
3. Column C contains the new part number (Example: CELL C2 = "900")
4. Column D to have the following formula, which will replace the Column B text found in Column A, with Column C text:
   =IF(IFERROR(FIND(B2,A2),1)<>1,REPLACE(A2,FIND(B2,A2),LEN(B2),C2),"")

Comment: A2<Whirlpool 6800 Microwave>B2<10097202> C2<WP10097202> .My mistake I need to look in column A for b2 and if found replace with c2 .................................................................................................................like the cells above 10097201 may be in a15000 when found I need to replace with WP10097202